# How do I name the series in my d3 chart?

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart that I've been chipping away at for a few days. The full chart is below:

```js
var dataset = [
  [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 5
  }, {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 4
  }, {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 2
  }, {
    "x": 4,
    "y": 7
  }, {
    "x": 5,
    "y": 23
  }],
  [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 10
  }, {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 12
  }, {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 19
  }, {
    "x": 4,
    "y": 23
  }, {
    "x": 5,
    "y": 17
  }],
  [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 22
  }, {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 28
  }, {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 32
  }, {
    "x": 4,
    "y": 35
  }, {
    "x": 5,
    "y": 43
  }]
];

var stack = d3.layout.stack();
stack(dataset);

var w = 400;
var h = 400;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
  .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,
    d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
      return d3.max(d, function(d) {
        return d.y0 + d.y;
      });
    })
  ])
  .range([0, h]);

//Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);
  });

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    console.log(d);
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (yScale(d.y0 + d.y));
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
```

```css
.text {
  font: 10px arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">

</div>
```

It works dandy with my data organized into x and y values by series:

```
var dataset = [
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 5 }, { "x": 2, "y": 4 }, { "x": 3, "y": 2 }, { "x": 4, "y": 7 }, { "x": 5, "y": 23 }], 
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 10 }, { "x": 2, "y": 12 }, { "x": 3, "y": 19 }, { "x": 4, "y": 23 }, { "x": 5, "y": 17 }], 
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 22 }, { "x": 2, "y": 28 }, { "x": 3, "y": 32 }, { "x": 4, "y": 35 }, { "x": 5, "y": 43 }] 
];
```

But I cannot figure out how to incorporate the names of each series into my JSON. This is valid JSON, but I don't know how to access it from my d3:

```
var dataset = [
  {"name": "oranges", 
  "data" : [{ "x": 1, "y": 5 }, { "x": 2, "y": 4 }, { "x": 3, "y": 2 }, { "x": 4, "y": 7 }, { "x": 5, "y": 23 }]},
  {"name": "apples", 
  "data" :[{ "x": 1, "y": 10 }, { "x": 2, "y": 12 }, { "x": 3, "y": 19 }, { "x": 4, "y": 23 }, { "x": 5, "y": 17 }]},
  {"name": "grapes", 
  "data" :[{ "x": 1, "y": 22 }, { "x": 2, "y": 28 }, { "x": 3, "y": 32 }, { "x": 4, "y": 35 }, { "x": 5, "y": 43 }]}
];
```

When I call the data with

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack();
stack(dataset);
```

how do I pull in just the data that `d3.layout.stack()` is expecting but keep the series names attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
stack(dataset);
```

do this

```
stack(dataset.map(function(d){ return d.data;}));//since your json structure is like that
```

Set domain like this

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].data.length))
  .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
```

Next when you make rectangles

```
var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.data; //set the data to return data as your json data structure is like that.
  }) //rest code as the way you doing
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h0qy55L8/)